# Ruby on Rails: Print preview overwrites itself on output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, printing

I'm working on an app and have built out a print function which does work, mostly. When a print preview is done, it appears as though the text output overwrites itself on the page.
[image: Print Overwrite]

Within my `application.html.erb` I do have this line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
```

And within my `print.scss` folder this is the first line:

```
@media print {
```

Do I need to add an `@` symbol within the `application.html.erb` tag for: `media: 'all'`   ?

Here is my full print.scss

```
    @media print {

body > *:not(#printSection) {
       display: none;
    }

#printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility: visible;

    #modal_invoice_number{font-size: 9px;}
    .page-header > small {
        color: #666;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

    #printSection {
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        width: 100%;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

.btn {
  display: none;
}
```

}

Comment: I don't know how to fix this, but the `@` is not the problem. The `@media` in your `print.scss` is a [Sass directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#media), whereas the `media:` in your `application.html.erb` is a Ruby keyword.

Comment: What happens is that you're rendering the view twice... but i can't understand why either :(